# How to find if a large Number is even or odd?

Tags: java

I was asked an interview question.How to find if a  very large number(more than the range of double) is odd or even?

I replied : Store the number in the array and find if the last digit is divisible by two.

```
public static boolean isEven(int[] verLargeNum)
{
    int size=verLargeNum.length;
    if(verLargeNum[size-1]%2!=0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

My question is: Is there a better approach ?

Comment: It's a good an answer as any.

Comment: Why not just `return verLargeNum[size - 1] % 2 != 0`?

Comment: @AntonH Actually, it's a terrible answer which shows a complete lack of understanding on how numbers are represented in the computer.

Comment: I'm afraid that this Question has lost something "in translation" between what you were asked at the interview and what has been relayed to us.  Specifically, what representation is being used.  Without this (or the ability to ask your interviewers) the Question can only be answered in vague / general terms.

Answer (score 3):

if your number doesn't have a decimal part, you can simply do a bit operation

```
If(MyBigNumber & 0x1) {
     odd
} else {
    even
}
```

Comment: I guess that the compiler would optimize the original code to your code anyway. So I would consider it bad practice to use bit operations here. It makes the code less readable without providing benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer looks correct, alternative way:
Since they are not specifying if the very large number has a primitive type or not, you can assume that the number acts as int, double, long etc...

```
String largeNumber = VERY_LARGE_NUMBER + "";
boolean isEven(String input){
    return Integer.parseInt(input.charAt(input.length()-1)+"")%2 == 0;
}
```

Comment: parese int for the last character only, so one digit